# Check if a variable is defined AND truthy at once in Twig

Tags: twig

In PHP I can do

```
<?php if ($someVar): ?>
```

This checks if a variable exists *and* if its value is different from a zero-like value like 0, null, '', and so on.

Is there any way to do so in Twig or do I need to write my own filter for that? At the moment, I must do

```
{% if someVar is defined and someVar %}
```

which is a pain when it comes to more complex templates.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are (at least) two ways of doing this without extending Twig. A third option is to extend Twig by creating e.g. a Twig function. I would probably choose the first way (using the `default` filter).

---

### By using the `default` filter

As @The_Unknown pointed out, you can also use the [`default` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html):

```
{% if someVar|default(null) %}
```

You can omit passing the default value to the filter, and even omit the parentheses. Then the value will default to an empty string (which is falsey). I.e. these two are equal and valid:

```
{% if someVar|default() %}
{% if someVar|default %}
```

Whichever style you choose (default to `null`, omit the value or omit the parens), stick to it. Be consistent.

[See TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/m1j2vy) for a demonstration that truthy values evaluate to `true` and falsey values evaluate to `false` (based on the table below).

---

### By setting `strict_variables` to `false`

By setting the environment variable `strict_variables` to `false`, you can skip the `if someVar is defined` part and do just `{% if someVar %}`. As described in [Twig's documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options):

> `strict_variables` *boolean*
>
> If set to `false`, Twig will silently ignore invalid variables
>   (variables and or attributes/methods that do not exist) and replace
>   them with a `null` value. When set to `true`, Twig throws an exception
>   instead (default to `false`).

Set the variable to `false` when creating a `Twig_Environment` instance:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, ['strict_variables' => false]);
```

If `someVar` is undefined, then `{% if someVar %}` is obviously `false`. [The `if` tag's documentation page](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html) describes the edge case rules for defined variables:

> The rules to determine if an expression is `true` or `false` are the same
>   as in PHP; here are the edge cases rules:
>
> ```
> Value                     Boolean evaluation
>
> empty string              false
> numeric zero              false
> whitespace-only string    true
> empty array               false
> null                      false
> non-empty array           true
> object                    true
> ```

[See TwigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ujy366) for a demonstration (`strict_variables` is set to `false` behind the "More options..." link in the header).

---

### By extending Twig

(Disclaimer: I wrote this approach before @The_Unknown pointed out that the `default` filter can also be used.)

If the idea of setting `strict_variables` to `false` is too general, you can also extend Twig. I'd argue that it's better to set `strict_variables` to `true` to avoid accidental errors caused by e.g. typos in variable names, so this approach might be better.

I don't think that you can create a filter to do this, as an undefined variable would still throw an exception. You might be able to create a custom tag, test or extension (see [Extending Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html) for ways to extend Twig); I'm going to create a custom function as it's probably the simplest approach.

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('istruthy', function($context, $var) {
     return array_key_exists($var, $context) && $context[$var];
 }, ['needs_context' => true]));
```

The `['needs_context' => true]` part is essential here, as then you will have access to `$context`, which contains the variables present in the current context. (You can e.g. put `var_dump($context)` above the return statement to see it yourself.)

If you want `istruthy` to support checking multiple variables at once, you can do this:

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_Function('istruthy', function($context, ...$vars) {
     foreach ($vars as $var) {
         if (!array_key_exists($var, $context) || !$context[$var]) {
             return false;
         }
     }

     return true;
 }, ['needs_context' => true]));
```

Then in Twig you can do:

```
{% if istruthy('foo') %} ... {% endif %}

{% if istruthy('foo') or istruthy('bar') %} ... {% endif %}


{# These two are the same: #}

{% if istruthy('foo') and istruthy('bar') and istruthy('baz') %} ... {% endif %}

{% if istruthy('foo', 'bar', 'baz') %} ... {% endif %}


{# Ternary operator can also be used: #}

{{ istruthy('foo') ? 'yep' : 'nope' }}
```

You might want to check in the `istruthy` function whether the arguments are strings or something else and then act accordingly. `array_key_exists` expects the first argument to be either a string or an integer.

Comment: Interesting, but seems like not a good idea to do so :-) It‘s very general.

Comment: I agree that it's best to set `strict_variables` to `true`. I updated my answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But I suspect, I found an even easier solution: what about {% if someVar|default() %}? It also works with arrays like {% if someArray.property|default() %}. Or do I get something wrong?

Comment: After quick testing looks like it would also work. You can add your own answer or I can add it to my answer with details.

Comment: @The_Unknown, I edited my answer with details about the `default` filter. Please feel free to add your own answer if you want as the idea of using the filter was yours. :-)

Answer (score 6):

The following works well:

```
{% if someVar ?? false %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what `@matias-kinnunen` and `@Sébastien` said, it's written [in the documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/default.html) that we must use `??` syntax only when we're using boolean variables. Otherwise, we must use the `default` filter. It's valid for every version of Twig (1.x, 2.x, 3.x).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34204003)